# How to pass context for an intent from a method of a class?

Tags: java, android

Error :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.adriitsolutions.prarthana.AdapterForListView.MyRequestForBloodRequirementListRecyclerView$1.onClick(MyRequestForBloodRequirementListRecyclerView.java:153)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
Here is my code.

java
((myViewHolderForRecyclerViewOfMenu) viewHolder).iv_my_request_view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // showLeadDetails(position);
        context.startActivity(new Intent( context , ViewDonorListActivity.class));
        Log.e("ONCLICK", "View Request");
    }
});

```
Adapter :  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {



        holder.sendAt.setText(mData.get(position).getSendAt());
        holder.radius.setText(mData.get(position).getRadius());
        holder.acceptedStatus.setText(mData.get(position).getAcceptedStatus());

        holder.requestBloodGrpType.setImageResource(mData.get( position ).getRequestBloodGrpType() );
        //holder.requestUrgenyType.setImageResource( mData.get( position ).getRequestUrgencyType() );

        holder.viewRequest.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,ViewDonorListActivity.class));
            }
        } );

       /* holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,ViewDonorListActivity.class));
            }
        });*/

    }
```

Comment: you can get context from the `View v`, just use v.getContext, i believe

Comment: Please share your adapter class and activity/fragment from where you are calling adapter

Comment: @a_local_nobody public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) this is what i have passed as args

Comment: @KishanMaurya I have now shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use **context** from **itemView** of ViewHolder -

**Solution**

```
Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ViewDonorListActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should post your full adapter class, cause we should see where do you initialize mContext.but by default you can get context by constructor method of adapter.

something like:

```
private List<Obj> list;
private Context mContext;

public AdapterRvBid(List<Obj> list, Context mContext) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mContext= mContext;
}
```

Comment: there's no need to pass context in to a recycler adapter, you can get it from the viewholder

Answer (score -1):

i made an edit like this in my main activity :

```
   public static Context mContext;

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
```

and later using this context i was able to pass an intent to call another activity !

```
Intent intent = new Intent( MyRequestActivity.getContext() , ViewDonorListActivity.class );
                        MyRequestActivity.getContext().startActivity( intent );
```

Comment: static Context objects lead to memory leaks.. check out the documentation on context and the adapter class..